# How to make a link work from a list of items in a table

Tags: grails, show

I want to make a link from this page navigate to a details page
but I am getting a 404 error.

```
    Here is the gsp:
<%@ page import="tictoc.Store" %>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="layout" content="main">
            <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'store.label', default: 'Store')}" />
            <title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <h1> Ticket Store </h1>
            <div>
                <table border=0 class="eventsTable">
                    <tr>

                        <th>Event</th>
                        <th>Start </th>
                        <th>End </th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>

                    <g:each var="event" in="${events}">

                    <tr>
                        <td><g:link action="display" controller="store" id="${event.id}">
                            ${event.name}
                            </g:link>
                        </td>
                        <td><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${event.startDate}"/></td>
                        <td><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${event.endDate}"/></td>
                        <td>${event.desc}</td>
                    </tr>

                    </g:each>

                </table>

            </div>
            <div class="paginateButtons">
                <g:paginate controller="store"
                    action="show"
                    max="5"
                    params="[name:active]"
                    total="${totalEvents}" />
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This is the controller and I have a GSP called buy.gsp that never gets shown.

```
        package tictoc
```

```
    import tictoc.Event 

    class StoreController {

        Event event
        static defaultAction = "activeEvents"

        def show = {
            log.error 'exec activeEvents'
            activeEvents()
        }

        def activeEvents = {
            log.error 'exec activeEvents'
            params.max = Math.min(params.int('max', 5), 100);
            params.offset = params.int('offset', 0)
            params.total  =  Event.count()
            params.sort   = params.sort ?: "name";
            params.order  = params.order ?: "asc";

            //  def max    = Math.min(params.int('max', 5), 100);
            //  def offset = params.offset?.toInteger() ?: 0
            //  def total =  Event.count()
            def eventList = Event.list(max: params.max, offset: params.offset)

            return [events:eventList, 
                    totalEvents:params.total,
                    active:params.active]                  
        }

        def detail = {
            log.error 'exec detail'
            def eventId = params.id
            log.error 'eventId:' + eventId
            render(view: "buy", model: [event: eventId])
        }

        def list = {
            params.max = Math.min(params.int('max', 25), 100);
            params.offset = params.int('offset', 0)
            params.sort = params.sort ?: "name";
            params.order = params.order ?: "asc";
            return [ myList: DomainObject.list(params) ]
        }


        def display = {
            println "display..........."
            def event = Event.findById(params.id)
            if(event) {
                println "EVENT IS $event"
                render(view:"buy", model:[event:event])
            }
            else {
                response.sendError 404
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the URL Mapping:

`class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = { "/"(controller:"store", action:'show') }    

}`

Comment: can you show your UrlMapping also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any mapping for URL `/store/display/6`, because you have mapped only one specified controller and specified action to exact url, by:

```
mappings = { "/"(controller:"store", action:'show') }
```

If you need to map diplay, you have to return (possible deleted) mapping:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
             constraints {
                // apply constraints here
             }
        }
        "/"(controller:"store", action:'show') 
    }
}
```

You can read more about Url mapping at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings

Comment: So every action I add to this application I need to add to this mapping thing... Ex:    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
             constraints {
                // apply constraints here
             }
        }
        "/"(controller:"store", action:'show') 
        
         "/"(controller:"user", action:'login') 
    }

Comment: pattern `/$controller/$action?/$id?` works for most standard actions, so you need your own mapping only if you have something specific

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing `Event.findById(params.id)` to `Event.get(params.id)`

It seems your event is null.

Comment: Same error:    
type Status report
message /tictoc/store/display/6
description The requested resource (/tictoc/store/display/6) is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide a more specific mapping like this:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/displayEvent/$id"(controller: 'store', action: 'display')
        "/"(controller:"store", action:'show') 
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for... is that mapping file the typical place all pages need to be added in order for the page to render?